# Query name and city using u-sql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I need to filter name and city from below nested json.

```
[
    {
        "Employee": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "Gender": "Male"
            }
        ],
        "Info": {
            "location": {
                "city": "Kuvala",
                "continent": "Asia",
                "country": "Singapore"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Employee": [
            {
                "name": "Mike",
                "Gender": "Male"
            }
        ],
        "Info": {
            "location": {
                "city": "Dhabi",
                "continent": "Asia",
                "country": "Dubai"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

> My code

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM @"/Assemblies/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM @"/Assemblies/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

DECLARE @InputFile string = @"/Source/example.blob";
DECLARE @output string = @"/Output/output.csv";

@json  =
    EXTRACT Employee String,
            Info String
    FROM @InputFile
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("*");

@CreateJSONTuple =
    SELECT   JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Employee) AS EmployeeData,
             JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Info) AS InfoData
    FROM @json;

@result =
    SELECT EmployeeData["name"] AS Name,
           JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(InfoData, "location") AS LocationData
    FROM @CreateJSONTuple;

OUTPUT @result
TO @output
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader : true, quoting : true);
```

> I ma getting error saying cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql.SqlArray' to 'string' please help.
>
> Please help me to get Name, City from this.
>    This should outputs: 
>    John Vulala
>    Mike Dhabi

Comment: Hi, we require some effort from your side. What is your U-sql script so far? There are numerous examples on the internet if you haven't any clue at all. Start with those first.

Comment: Hi @PeterBons , I have updated with my code. I am new and not getting proper documentation from beginner to expert level. Please help me this time.

Comment: Please help..,,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because the contents of the **Employee** elements is defined as an array:

```
"Employee": [
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "Gender": "Male"
        }
    ]
```

Try changing the **Employee** elements to something like this:

```
"Employee": {
            "name": "Mike",
            "Gender": "Male"
        }
```

**Update**

It seems you might need to perform **JsonTuple** on the array item, so this might work:

```
@result =
SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(EmployeeData[0])["name"] AS Name,
       JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(InfoData, "location") AS LocationData
FROM @CreateJSONTuple;
```

One thing to note, if the **Employee** array might hold more than one item, you'll probably need to use [Cross Apply Explode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/cross-apply/explode).

**Update 2**

Unfortunately, this is the last thing I can think of. try replacing:

```
@CreateJSONTuple =
SELECT   JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Employee) AS EmployeeData,
         JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Info) AS InfoData
FROM @json;

@result =
SELECT EmployeeData["name"] AS Name,
       JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(InfoData, "location") AS LocationData
FROM @CreateJSONTuple;
```

With this:

```
@CreateJSONTuple =
SELECT   JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Employee).Values AS EmployeeData,
         JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Info) AS InfoData
FROM @json;
@result =
SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(employee)["name"] AS Name,
       JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(InfoData, "location") AS LocationData
FROM @CreateJSONTuple
CROSS APPLY
    EXPLODE(EmployeeData) AS employees(employee) ;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can not change it, the data i am getting is from third party.

Comment: copiler error for EmployeeData[0]["name"]: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Comment: i tried another way and got copiler error for EmployeeData["0"]["name"]: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Still same exception : cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'